# Power BI - dynamically build a supersession conversion table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm having a hard time to figure out a neat solution to what seems to be a simple query.

The scenario is as follow:

- At my store I sell items that can be replaced by other items (i.e. have supersession). For example, until a certain date I may had for sale a jacket (Product ID = Jacket_01) that was replaced by a new jacket (Product ID = Jacket_25).
- These supersessions can happen successively. This means that Jacket_01 can be replaced by Jacket_25, which can be replaced by Jacket_98, which can be replaced by Jacket_99.
- More than one product can be replaced by a common new product. This means that Jacket_25 can be replaced by Jacket_98, but Jacket_70 can also be replaced by Jacket_98.
- I have two raw tables (as images below): a) the supersession table, with the information of which old product ID was replaced by which new product id; and b) the sales table.

[image]

[image]

- At the end of the day I want to know the latest product ID's sales amount, but considering all its priors products ID (as image below).

[image]

I need a dynamically solution as both the supersession and sales table are updated constantly.

It appears to me the the key step here is to build what I called a conversion table, such as the one below, that would give me the consolidated information of the old product ID and the latest new product ID, but I'm not being able to build this table dynamically with the resources I know in DAX or PowerQuery.

[image]

Any ideas please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In PQ, I would unpivot to create a single column of all the jacket types; remove duplicates and sort in ascending order; then check your Old ID to see if the Old ID exists in that list.  If it does, add it to your Sum, or assign it the last value in the List.  If you have multiple products in the list, the coding gets more complex, but the principle is the same.